# place an image over a button

Tags: android, button, view, drawable

I have a button on my main screen. I'd like to display a padlock image on the button when a global variable changes its state.

What would be the best way of setting an image on a standard button? Do i have to make the button an imageButton or do i simply setBackground...()?

```
Button signin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsignin);
               // signin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.signin);

                alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.3F, 0.8F); //Set opacity - Range 0.0 to 1.0
                alpha.setDuration(0); // Set animation duration
                alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Maintaining the effect to the button
                signin.startAnimation(alpha);
                signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        .....

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better if you use button and then give its attributes in the xml file so that you can play with the attributes like pressed state. But if you give setBackground="image path" then you won't be able to give properties like `state_pressed`.

Comment: +1 for using selectors , here is a full example about how to use `selectors` : http://wp.me/p3V0Ps-t

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to have a relative layout holding both an imageview and a standard button so the button can have text while also showing the button state in the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Often or not, I don't even use a button when I am dealing with a depression of something that will hold an image, I'll just use an ImageView with different states.  But as mentioned, using a selector makes the job considerably easier from the XML code without having to worry about handling toggles on your own end; multiple ways to achieve the desired effect.